# Extract coded free text into new variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has a free text variable that I have inserted specific code to categorize an infection after describing it. Example in the free text box I wrote `"ear infection, got antibiotics, ENT"`. Not all entries have an infection and some entries have more than one year `"ear infection, E coli diarrhea, ENT, GI"`. What would be the best way to create a new variable that pulls out my coded infections including if I have more than one and then puts `NA` for the ones that dont have any. I made sure the free text code I put in to the field was always the same and always capitalized. I have figured out how to remove punctuation so just trying to figure out how to use stringer to get it out.

Envision something like this:

| ID | other_infx_free_text | other_infxn_1 | other_infxn_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blah, blah, blah | NA | NA |
| 2 | blah, RESP, blah | RESP | NA |
| 3 | blah, RESP, blah, ENT | RESP | ENT |

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (can be automated further with a loop for arbitrary number of columns):

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(ID=1:3,    other_infx_free_text = c('blah, blah, blah', 'blah, RESP, blah  RESP', 'blah, RESP, blah, ENT   RESP    ENT'))
df
#  ID           other_infx_free_text   other_infxn_1
#1  1               blah, blah, blah              NA
#2  2          blah, RESP, blah\tRESP           RESP
#3  3 blah, RESP, blah, ENT\tRESP\tENT          RESP

lst <- lapply(str_extract_all(df$other_infx_free_text, "[A-Z]+"), unique)

df$other_infxn_1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) ifelse (length(x) >= 1, x[1], NA) )
df$other_infxn_2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) ifelse (length(x) >= 2, x[2], NA) )
df
#  ID           other_infx_free_text  other_infxn_1  other_infxn_2
#1  1               blah, blah, blah             NA             NA
#2  2          blah, RESP, blah\tRESP           RESP            NA
#3  3 blah, RESP, blah, ENT\tRESP\tENT          RESP           ENT
```

Comment: Thank you Sandipan. Let's say I wanted to create the columns with only one infection per column so that if it finds "RESP" in the free text field, then other_infxn_1 will return Yes or 1 and if not, then No or 0. Would that make it easier?